# MySql Sum of Count If

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with every login by all users. 
I want to run a query that will pull the number of times each user logs in but limit it to 4 if the user logged in more than 4 times on a day.
And then do a sum to get the total number of logins.
Further to this I want to pull back the time frame for the total number of logins. So I specify the total number of logins as 100 then the query must pull back the earliest date, going back from today and counting the number of logins (limited at 4 if above 4) per user.

My query so far to get the list of totals limited to 4 per user:

```
SELECT (case when (count(l.user_id) > 4) then 4 else count(l.user_id) end) as cappedcount 
FROM `logins` l 
where l.store_id = 908 
and l.login_dt > '2018-04-17 00:00:00' and l.login_dt < '2018-04-18 23:59:59' 
group by l.user_id order by cappedcount desc
```

I'm specifying the date range at the moment but don't want to do that in the final query.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you only want to look at the last four logins per user and day and ignore their earlier logins. From this set you want the last 100 logins.

So the first task is to get the four last logins per user and day, which would usually be solved with window functions, but MySQL doesn't feature them. So count in a subquery instead (which may take long):

```
select *
from logins
where
(
  select count(*)
  from logins later
  where later.user_id = logins.user_id
    and date(later.login_dt) = date(logins.login_dt)
    and later.login_dt > logins.login_dt
) < 4
order by login_dt desc
limit 100;
```

I suggest to provide the following index for this query:

```
create index idx_logins on logins (user_id, login_dt);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I failed to mention the cap of 4 logins per user is per day. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: If you want to restrict the lookup to the same day, then add `and date(later.login_dt) = date(logins.login_dt)` to the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of MySQL you user? Because as far as I know `with clause` is only supported in recent versions of MySQL.

I believe the answer to your first request is something like :

```
select sum(cntx) from (
  select user_id, date(login_time), least(count(*), 4) cntx
    from logins
   where login_time between '2018-04-10 00:00:00' and '2018-04-17 00:00:00'
   group by user_id, date(login_time)
) x
```

as you can view it in [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/332105/11/0).

---

For your second question, I have following answer, I believe it's not the best solution, but it works on MySQL 5.6. In next MySQL version (MySQL 8) you can use with clause which provides better solution for this question. I use views in the solution to skip duplicate queries:

```
create view xlogins as
select user_id, date(login_time) xdt, least(count(*), 4) xcnt
 from logins
group by user_id, date(login_time);

create view xxlogins as
select distinct xdt, (select sum(x2.xcnt)
                        from xlogins x2
                       where x2.xdt >= x1.xdt) sumx
  from xlogins x1;

select min(x1.xdt)
  from xxlogins x1
  join xxlogins x2 on x1.xdt < x2.xd
 where x1.sumx >= 100
   and x2.sumx <= 100
```

Find the solution in this [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b3020/8/0), I've just changed the 100 to 10.

Comment: Thanks. I've got to this point, but now I want the query to be generated with a having sum(cntx) = 100 which will output the records building that total. Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I get you want to find days with last 100 logins (with maximum 4 logins per user per day), am I correct?